# Load node JS Web app so slow in VPS with pm2

Tags: node.js, express, vps, pm2

Im using `pm2 start app.js --watch` but it's very slow to reload my web app. It always must to refresh the browser for get the page fast. What should i do?

Comment: And also use pm2 start app.js is slow too. Sometimes my app is fast, but sometimes is so slow even doesnt reload

Comment: Sounds like you need to raise this with the authors of the PM2 utilities.